# Google Scholar not listing articles that were first posted to medRxiv

Tags: google-scholar

I have found that when I post a preprint to medRxiv it appears on Google Scholar soon afterwards. But when the article is accepted after peer review by a journal, the journal article is not detected by Google Scholar - it only finds the original medRxiv article. On the other hand, if an article is accepted without a preprint on medRxiv, then Google Scholar detects it soon after publication with no problem.

It is possible to manually edit the medRxiv entry to reflect the published version, but this doesn't link to the published version in the same way that automatically listed entries do. For instance, users cannot click directly to the article, and the number of citations it has is always listed as zero.

Anyone has encountered this problem also?